# Copy column when condition is met?

Tags: excel

I want to copy one column to another in excel only when another column contains particular value which are stored in third column?

I tried if condition but that doesn't help anything

Comment: Try `=IF(B1="Your Value",A1,"")`.

Comment: I have to search value in a column not compare with two cells.

Comment: Its hard to guess without seeing sample data. Then can try FILTER function.

Comment: got it right using LOOKUP command

Answer (score 0):

Got it finally using LOOKUP command.